# Odoo 13 confirmation box for ORM write method

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, erp, odoo-13

I want to make a confirmation window for the change in Odoo 13 record. For example, when the start and end times of an order change, a confirmation popup window appears (yes / no). 
How can you do this?

This method does not work in  `write()` function, but it works in other functions:

```
return {
     'view_type': 'form',
     'view_mode': 'form',
     'view_id': self.env.ref ('my_module.my_view'). id,
     'res_model': 'my.model',
     'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
     'target': 'new',
     'context': {}
}
```

Comment: The `write` return value will be evaluated as bool, so it won't work there. Your required workflow (confirmation popup on save) is contrary to Odoo's normal workflow. There is actually only one confirmation dialog which can be added to (record) actions/buttons. What about a warning message returned by an onchange trigger for your mentioned fields?

Comment: Agreed with @CZoellner. Warning popup on a field onchange is best.